# SVG viewport not aligned left in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, alignment

There simple inline svg with specified viewBox:

https://jsfiddle.net/updLm0rv/2/

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg class="svg-inlined"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0320 12">
     <g>
        <circle r="6" cx="6" cy="6" fill="gray"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And with restricted height:

```
.svg-inlined {
   height: 14px;
   display: block;
}
```

Chrome and firefox draws it left aligned
[image]

But IE draws it center aligned:

[image]

**Any idea, how to make IE align image left as Chrome and Firefox do?**

Note: I do need autoscale svg-image width keeping proportions, to match the sepcified height. So, I can't remove viewBox or remove height, or sepcify width.

My use case: I making placeholder for the text, while content loading. So, specify image height related to font-size, so it adapted to current text size. That's why I need viewBox and height specified.

UPD: I can't use `<img>` tag due to [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=812239)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To adjust the alignment/mapping of the »view box« to the »view port« you can use the `preserveAspectRatio` Attribute of the `<svg>`. There are a couple of options there, have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio).

My bet is:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">…</svg>
```